# Radius of Convergence of the Derivative of a Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series

I encountered a standard problem in my Complex Analysis book that, given a power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ that has a radius of convergence equal to R, wanted us to find the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{2n} $ My first thought was to apply Cauchy-Hamard to the problem and I obtained of radius of convergence $R'=\sqrt{R}$. However, a standard result in Complex Analysis tells us that $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n} $ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}na_{n}z^{n-1} $ have the same radius of convergence. Then I applied the following reasonining. $$\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{2n}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{2n!}{n!}a_{n}z^{n}  $$ And by Cauchy-Hamard
$$R=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n\to\infty}\lvert\frac{2n!}{n!}a_{n}\rvert^{\frac{1}{n}}}\to0$$
My general question is if a derivative has the same radius of convergence as the original function, do the derivatives of all orders of the function have the same radius of convergence? And in this case, where have I gone wrong as the radius of convergence is certainly not 0. I apologize if this has already been asked somewhere.

Comment: Your second argument is wrong because the expression $\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ makes no sense – $n$ cannot be both the summation index *and* the order of the derivative taken.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry, I had a typo in the problem, that should be $z^{2n}$ as the summand.

Comment: $\frac{d^{n}}{dz^{n}}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{2n}$ does not make sense either ...

Comment: $|z^2| < R \iff |z| < \sqrt{R}$

Comment: @MartinR I see the problem now, thank you for the help!